# Thread priority (how to get fixed order)

Tags: c#, multithreading

in console because threads sleep with randoms it will show the order of threads
3,2,1 or 1,2,3 or ...
how can I have fixed order?
and why when I set priority it doeasn't effect the code?
      // ThreadTester.cs
        // Multiple threads printing at different intervals.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace threadTester
    {
        // class ThreadTester demonstrates basic threading concepts
        class ThreadTester
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Create and name each thread. Use MessagePrinter's
                // Print method as argument to ThreadStart delegate.
                MessagePrinter printer1 = new MessagePrinter();
                Thread thread1 =
                   new Thread(new ThreadStart(printer1.Print));
                thread1.Name = "thread1";

                MessagePrinter printer2 = new MessagePrinter();
                Thread thread2 =
                   new Thread(new ThreadStart(printer2.Print));
                thread2.Name = "thread2";

                MessagePrinter printer3 = new MessagePrinter();
                Thread thread3 =
                   new Thread(new ThreadStart(printer3.Print));
                thread3.Name = "thread3";

                Console.WriteLine("Starting threads");

                // call each thread's Start method to place each 
                // thread in Started state
                thread1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                thread2.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
                thread3.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                thread1.Start();
                thread2.Start();
                thread3.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Threads started\n");
                Console.ReadLine();

            } // end method Main

        } // end class ThreadTester

        // Print method of this class used to control threads
        class MessagePrinter
        {
            private int sleepTime;
            private static Random random = new Random();

            // constructor to initialize a MessagePrinter object
            public MessagePrinter()
            {
                // pick random sleep time between 0 and 5 seconds
                sleepTime = random.Next(5001);
            }

            // method Print controls thread that prints messages
            public void Print()
            {
                // obtain reference to currently executing thread
                Thread current = Thread.CurrentThread;

                // put thread to sleep for sleepTime amount of time
                Console.WriteLine(
                   current.Name + " going to sleep for " + sleepTime);

                Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);

                // print thread name
                Console.WriteLine(current.Name + " done sleeping");

            } // end method Print

        } // end class MessagePrinter
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use threads precisely because you do not care about having things happen in a particular order, but want either:

1. At the same time, if there are enough cores to allow them to happen together.
2. With some making progress while others are waiting for something.
3. Interleaved with paying attention to I/O or user-input, so as to continue being responsive.

In each of these cases, you just don't care that you don't know just which bit of what will happen when.

However:

1. You may still care about the order of certain sequences. In the simplest case, you just have these things happen in sequence within the same thread, while other things happen in other threads. More complicated cases can be served by chaining tasks together.
2. You may want the results from different threads to finally be put into a different order. The simplest approach is to put them all into order after they've all finished, though you can also sort results as they come (tricky though).

For ideal performance, there should be one thread running on each core (or possibly two on a hyperthreaded core, but that has further complications) at all times. Let's say you have a machine with 4 cores and 8 tasks you need done.

If the tasks involved a lot of waiting on I/O, then four will start, each will reach a point where it's waiting on that I/O, and allow one of the other tasks to make some progress. Chances are that even with the number of tasks being twice the number of cores, it'll still end up with plenty of idle time. If each task was going to take 20seconds, then doing them on different threads will probably have them all done in just a little over 20seconds, since all of them were spending most of their 20seconds waiting on something else.

If you are doing tasks that keep the CPU busy all the time (not much waiting for memory and certainly not for I/O) then you will be able to have four such tasks going at a time, while the others are waiting for them to either finish, or give up their slice of time. Here if each took 20seconds, the best you could hope for is a total time of about 40seconds (and that's assuming that no other thread from any process on the system wants the CPU, that you've a perfect lack of overhead in setting up the threads, etc).

In cases where there is more work to do (active work to do, rather than waiting for I/O to complete, another thread to release a lock, etc.) than cores, the OSs scheduler will swap around between different threads that want to be active. The exact details differs from OS to OS (different Windows versions, including some important differences between desktop and server set ups, take different approaches, different Linux versions with some particularly big changes from 2.4 to 2.6 and different Unixes, etc. all have different strategies).

One thing they all have in common is the common goal of making sure stuff gets done.

Thread priorities and process priorities are ways to influence this scheduling. With Windows, whenever there's more threads waiting to work than cores to work, those of the highest priority get given CPU time in a round-robin fashion. Should there be no threads of that priority, then those of the next lowest are given CPU time, then the next and so on.

This is a great way to have things grind things to a halt. It can lead to complications where a thread that was given high priority (presumably because it's work is considered particularly crucial) is waiting on a thread given low priority (presumably because its work is considered less important and one wants it to always cede time to the others), and the low-priority thread keeps not being given CPU time, because there's always more threads of higher priority than available cores. Hence the supposedly high-priority thread gets no CPU time at all.

To fix this situation, windows will occasionally promote the threads that haven't run in a long time. This fixes things, but now means you've got the supposedly low-priority threads bursting along as super-high priority to the detriment not just of the rest of the application but also the rest of the sytem.

(One of the best things about having a multi-core system, is it means your computing experience is less affected by people who set the priority of threads!)

If you use a debugger to stop a multi-threaded .NET application and examine the threads you'll probably find that all of them are at normal except for one at highest. This one at highest will be the finalizer thread and its running at highest priority is one of the reasons its important that finalizers should not take a long time to execute - having work done at highest priority is a bad thing and while it is justified in this case, it must end as soon as possible.

At least 95% of all other cases where someone sets the priority of a thread is a logical bug - it'll do nothing most of the time and allows things to get very messed up the rest. They can be used well (or we wouldn't have that ability at all), but should definitely be put in the "advanced techniques" category. (I like to spend my free time experimenting with multi-threading techniques that would count as excessive and premature optimisation most of the time, and I still hardly ever touch priorities).

In your example, priority will have little effect because each thread spends most of its time sleeping, so whichever thread does want CPU time can get it for the few nano-seconds it needs to run. What it could do though is cause the whole thing to become needlessly slower should you run it on a machine where the cores are also busy with other normal threads. In this case `thead1` wouldn't get any CPU time at first (because there's always a higher priority thread that wants the CPU), then after 3seconds the scheduler would realise its been starved for an eternity the terms of CPU speeds (9billion CPU cycles or so) and give it a burst to highest priority for long enough to let it screw with the timing of vital windows services! Luckily it then sleeps and then does a minute amount of work before finishing, so it does no harm, but if it was doing anything real it could have some really nasty effects on the entire system's performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't guarantee when windows will execute a particular thread.  You can make suggestions to the OS (I.E. the priority level) but ultimately Windows will decide when, what and where.

If you want to ensure that 1 starts before 2 which in turns starts before 3 you should make thread 1 start thread 2 and thread 2 start thread 3.

Comment: you mean i should set a boolean?

Comment: boolean? No, I mean you should start thread 2 when thread 1 starts (and in turn 3 on 2).  There are several ways you could achieve this, which is best depends on the context of you app. For example you could have the work on thread one fire a event that results in thread 2 start, or thread 1 work could explicitly start thread 2.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are considered lightweight processes, in that they run completely independent of each other. If your task relies heavily on the order in which threads execute, you probably shouldn't be using threads.

Otherwise, you need to look at the [thread synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) constructs that the .NET framework provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can not synchronize threads like this. If you need the work done in a certain order, don't use seperate threads, or use ResetEvents or something similar.

Comment: I am a newbie can you tell me more clear? can you show me an example?

Comment: I can't give you a whole primer on threading, no. But I can tell you that generally, you should not use threads if you need things to happen in a certain order.

Comment: then where priority is useful?

Comment: That's way beyond your skill level at this point. My short explanation would make it seem like they are useful for what you are doing, but there are way too many variables there. Simple version: priorities are *not* to synchronize your threads... they are to *generally* give higher priority to certain threads. It still does not guarantee X completes before Y starts.

Comment: For priority: Say you have thread A which does important work and thread B which does unimportant "background" work. Then you can give thread B a lower priority, which means the scheduler will give it less time (at least if time is constrained). This means that in that case thread A will get more time than thread B.

Comment: @DanielRose Though mostly you don't even say that, since it can lead to priority inversion and all manner of nastiness.

Answer (score 0):

Thread scheduling is never guaranteed. Order is never preserved unless you explicitly force it through your code via locks/etc.

Comment: how I can use lock? I saw the link of Jonathon Reinhart but how?