# Why does thread priority have no effect?

Tags: c#

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => WriteY("11"));
            t.Start();
            t.IsBackground = true;
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write("x");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void WriteY(string ss)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                Console.Write(ss);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, I think the "x" thread should complete first, since its priority is heighest. but the result is that they are still switching.

Comment: Priority shouldn't have anything to do with what finishes first

Comment: [Thread Priorities are Evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8683938/11683

Comment: Note that `Console.Write` is a very bad example case as this is reflected on the main thread. Better calculate some difficult number.

Comment: @Sayse - on a single-CPU machine, you would expect the higher priority thread to be scheduled ahead of the lower priority one, which would likely affect which thread finishes first (given they are performing roughly the same operation). However no mention is made of what system it's being run on - one with 2 or more CPUs could easily schedule the lower priority thread on one CPU and the higher priority on another, resulting in the "switching" being seen.

Comment: For so many different reasons. Have look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) where it says `Operating systems are not required to honor the priority of a thread.` or [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority.aspx), the part in which it is talking about OS implementation dependencies.

Comment: @Iridium - It is still very unsafe to assume that higher priority will finish first which I'm sure you'd agree with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Thread priority has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038592/java-thread-priority-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, regardless of priorities, **you can not make any assumptions about which parallel job finishes first**.

Also, please read this article by Jeff Atwood about why using thread priorities is a bad idea.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html

In case of tl;dr just one quote: *No matter how brilliant a programmer you may be, I can practically guarantee you won't be able to outsmart the programmers who wrote the scheduler in your operating system*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one CPU(-core) on your PC which is available this is "normal", as Thread 1 is running on CPU/core 1 and thread 2 on CPU/core 2.
I think if you reporduce the same with more threads then available cores or running e.g. Prime95 in the background to use 100% of your CPU it should make a difference, but in case of <= threads then (available) CPUs/corse the scheduler will run each thread on its own core and (if they are doing ~ the same) they will finish the same time...