# Why thread does not run according to priority

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have one problem in this program  i want to run thread based on priority but when i run this program so output is

```
say hello
say bye
```

But I want to change order by priority please help me. Because priory of `say bye` is high

```
say bye
say hello
```

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    public void Sayhello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("say hello");
    }

    public void Saybye()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("say bye");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program ob = new Program();

        Thread  th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ob.Sayhello));
        th.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        th.Start();

        Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ob.Saybye));
        th1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        th1.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that first thread is completing before the second one is even created. It doesn't take long to write to the console high priority or not.

Comment: I think you can find a suitable answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052534/why-does-thread-priority-have-no-effect?rq=1

Comment: I wouldn't usually be so straightforward, but... If you really really really don't know what you're doing, just leave thread priorities alone. It's not a simple setting to let you control how threads are executed, it's a very complicated mechanism designed for extreme scenarios, not day to day use. Maybe you should repost your question asking how to solve your actual problem, rather than trying a scenario that doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Thread priority is used by the system to decide which thread to run when there are more threads ready to run than there are processors. In that situation, higher priority threads get to run first.

In your case it's plausible that either:

1. The low priority thread has already started before the high priority thread is ready to run, or,
2. You have sufficient processors that both threads can run simultaneously.

Thread priority is not a tool that can be used to ensure order of execution. You need to use thread synchronization objects for that.

In general, it is rather rare that you set the priority of a thread. Generally it is best to let the operating system decide how to schedule threads.

Answer (score 0):

Starting th1 after th will probably do it:

```
th1.Start();
th.Start()
```

But there is still no guarantee, you need to block till one is done, which begs the question why use threads at all?

```
Sayhello();
Saybye();
```

If you must you need to signal when hello is done so bye can proceed:

```
private ManualResetEvent waitHandel;

public void Sayhello()
{
    Console.WriteLine("say hello");
    waitHandel.Set();
}

public void Saybye()
{
    waitHandel.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("say bye");
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    waitHandel = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    Thread  th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ob.Sayhello));
    th.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
    th.Start();

    Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ob.Saybye));
    th1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    th1.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```